# Is checked exception behaviour still appropriate in view of Kotlin?

Tags: spring-transactions

The default behaviour of @Transactional methods that throw exceptions is quite widely discussed (eg see [search results here](https://www.google.com/search?q=checked%20exceptions%20spring%20transaction&oq=checked%20exceptions%20spring%20transaction)) and clearly documented in the [Javadoc of org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.DefaultTransactionAttribute](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/DefaultTransactionAttribute.html#rollbackOn-java.lang.Throwable-). Essentially, runtime exceptions and errors cause a rollback, but checked exceptions do not.

However, with increased use of Kotlin I think there is increased danger of fairly catastrophic problems creeping into code unawares, and I'm wondering if there should be any consideration of changing the behaviour of DefaultTransactionAttribute to be in line with the behaviour of [TransactionTemplate](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-tx/src/main/java/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.java), which does rollback on checked exceptions.

The problem I uncovered was in a piece of code where a @Transactional Kotlin method was indirectly calling a Java method which declared a checked exception - an Exception which would actually occur very very rarely.

The chain of Kotlin method calls leading to the Java method did not catch and deal with the checked exception at any point, and of course the compiler is perfectly happy with that. Inarguably the writer of the code or a reviewer should have spotted the omission, but realistically, it is the sort of problem that can quite easily be missed. If it is missed the outcome is really quite bad - in my case the transaction was committed even though only half the expected entities had been created at the point everything blew up, and the actual exception was swallowed in TransactionAspectSupport so wasn't visible anywhere. I only discovered the problem because (luckily) there was an integrity constraint violation in a subsequent piece of code.

Is this a case where the impact is high enough that the framework code should protect developers from themselves? In Java it is very difficult to accidentally make this mistake, but in Kotlin it is a different matter.

Comment: For the benefit of people who don't know “the default behaviour of @Transactional methods that throw checked exceptions”, could the question make this a little more explicit?  At the least, if it's “well documented and widely discussed”, a couple of links would help; as would links to `DefaultTransactionAttribute` and `TransactionTemplate`.

Comment: This also seems like more of a question for Spring discussion forums/mailing lists than for SO.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @gidds- will edit when back at a proper keyboard (On phone right now).

Comment: @Alexey Romanov, I agree but I thought spring discussion  forums were deprecated in favour of tagged questions here. Will double check.

Comment: @Chris Apparently so. I'd think questions like this one need an actual discussion and not just an answer, but that's on them.